# Turn off URL rewriting in Cassette

Tags: asp.net, cassette

I am using the most excellent [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) for bundling assets in ASP.NET. However, there are times when it would be handy to turn off the URL rewriting altogether. I know there are solutions for preventing minification or stopping bundling, but I want the Cassette HtmlHelper to simply (temporarily) emit the original asset URLs.

For example, rather than emitting:

```
<script src="/cassette.axd/asset/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js?DXiW4rsj-I4m5SsioHU1CzVN9Ec=" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Cassette would emit the original:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Some background: I am playing around with InProcess bootstrapping of an ASP.NET MVC application for Integration Tests. The '.axd' and Url-rewriting aspects of Cassette are just one more thing to worry about, so it would be handy to effectively turn Cassette off in some tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I posted the same question on the Cassette Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cassette/IlbIBPSHoVQ), and the lead dev (Andrew Davey) reckons the simplest way to achieve this is to wrap the Cassette HTML Helper methods with a helper of your own which strips out the '/cassette.axd/asset/' part of the URL. The query-string hash parameter at the end of the URL is then simply ignored.

As Andrew says, it's a bit of a hack but I'm quite happy to do this when running integration tests.

(The linked Google Group thread also suggests a more elegant path of exploration to achieve this.)

Answer (score 1):

IsHtmlRewritingEnabled in your Cassette configuration settings defaults to true. set it to false. See [here](http://getcassette.net/documentation/v1/configuration) for more details

Comment: Although this stops minification and bundling, it doesn't stop the URL being rewritten.